# paths in multiproject angular tsconfig

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application in angular, that I would like to split in 2 projects and a library.

In my original project, I had a `tsconfig.json` file with the following

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@e2e/*": ["e2e/src/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Now, since I created a project, and those paths are concerning that project only, I moved those paths to the newly create `projects/projectName/tsconfig.app.json`

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@e2e/*": ["e2e/src/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    },
    "types": []
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

and

but vscode show error on all my imports, and at compilation too. It does work if I add the paths to the root `tsconfig.json` but since I want `@app` to point to the current project (in every project) this solution would cause me to have `@app1 @app2 ...`

Comment: Since you're building angular, did you also include this change of location in the `angular.json` file?

i'm also not sure about the relative paths, they might be relative to the project root, not to the tsconfig.json?

Comment: this is done automatically when you create a sub project so yes

Comment: what I see is that `tsconfig.app.json` is ignored concerning `path` so they need to be added on the root... but there must be another way/solution